# How to solve $\int \:\frac{3x^2+1}{x^3+2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int \:\frac{3x^2+1}{x^3+2}dx$$

I am not sure how to do it. I tried using partial fractions but you can not factor $x^3+2$, and changing the variable with $u$ does not seem to work either. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: The easy part is $\frac{3x^2}{x^3+2}$ indeed $(\log x^3+2)'=\frac{3x^2}{x^3+2}$.

Comment: But I guess that does not help at all because the remaining integral would be $ \int \frac1{x^3+2}\mathrm{d}x$ and I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: You can factor any polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ into linear or 2nd degree polynomials.
Here,you can factor  $x^3+2=(x+\sqrt[3] 2)(x^2-\sqrt[3]2x+\sqrt[3]4)$, if its any help.

Comment: Separate the two and in the second integral take sub $1+2/x^3=t$

Comment: This is it ! You can combine gimusi's trick and Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer. The linear and quadratic factors are mutually prime so you get $$\frac{1}{x^3+2}=\frac{A}{x+\sqrt[3]{2}}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2-\sqrt[3]{2}x+2^{2/3}}$$ the second  can be written $$\frac{\lambda Q'}{Q}+\frac{\mu}{Q}$$ where $$Q(x)=x^2-\sqrt[3]{2}x+2^{2/3}$$

Comment: $\int \frac1{x^3+2}\mathrm{d}x=\int \frac1{x^3(1+\frac2{x^3})}\mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{\frac1{x^3}}{1+\frac2{x^3}}\mathrm{d}x$, $t=1+\frac2{x^3},\mathrm{d}t=-\frac6{x^4}\mathrm{d}x$ , $-\frac16\int \frac1{t}~\text{x}~\mathrm{d}t$ and then?@Pi_die_die

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: write your integral in the form

$$\int \frac{3x^2+1}{(x+\sqrt[3]{2})(x^2-\sqrt[3]{2}x+2^{2/3})}dx$$

Comment: I guess you could apply partial fractions to this "new" but it seems to me that this gets really messy. Is there no other way?

Comment: I think here in this case is no other way, let me say i know no other way.

Comment: Yes. Technically you can factor anything and apply partial fractions in the real numbers, but I was trying to avoid this. I suppose there truly is no other way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can clean things up a little by doing a substitution $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}x$ first; doesn't help a lot, but it makes the numbers better.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfy gives 
a number of forms,
the first of which is

$ \log(x^3 + 2) - \dfrac{\log(2^{1/3} x^2 - 2^{2/3} x + 2)}{6\  2^{2/3}} 
+ \dfrac{\log(2^{2/3} x + 2)}{3\ 2^{2/3}} 
+ \dfrac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{2^{2/3} x - 1}{\sqrt{3}})}{2^{2/3} \sqrt{3}}
+C
$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=x^3$ and you can reduce it down to:

$$\frac13\int\frac{u^{-\frac23}}{u+2}du+\int\frac{1}{u+2}du$$

I believe it can be taken from here

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{3x^2+1}{x^3+2}dx=\int \frac{3x^2}{x^3+2}dx+\int \frac{dx}{x^3+2}$$
$$I=\log(x^3+2)+\int \frac{dx}{x^3+2}$$ For the remaining integral, let
$$x=\sqrt[3]2\, t\implies dx=\sqrt[3]2\,dt$$
$$J=\int \frac{dx}{x^3+2}=\frac{\sqrt[3]2}2 \int \frac{dt}{t^3+1}$$
Now
$$t^3+1=(t-1)(t-a)(t-b)$$ Partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1 {t^3+1}=\frac{1}{(a-1) (a-b) (t-a)}+\frac{1}{(b-1) (b-a) (t-b)}+\frac{1}{(a-1) (b-1) (t-1)}$$ Integrate to get a weighted sum of logarithms with complex values (the weights are complex too) and recombine them to get the answer already given.